# Using htaccess to fix links on modified URI

Tags: .htaccess

Having a website with the following URLs:

www.mydomain.com/search/keyword

www.mydomain.com/about

www.mydomain.com/user

On .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^search/(.*) search.php?q=$1 [qsa]
RewriteRule ^about about.php
RewriteRule ^user user.php
```

When clicking on "about" on the page with the search request I want to access the URL "www.mydomain.com/about" instead of "www.mydomain.com/search/about".

Is it possible to be achieved with .htaccess? Perhaps identifying search.php on HTTP_REFERER?

I want hyperlinks to be written as , and not  because of directory structure.

Adding the following lines to htaccess gives me a partial solution:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} search/(.*)
RewriteRule ^search/(.*) $1 [qsa]
```

The "info" link on the search points to the url www.mydomain.com/search/info, that redirects successfully to the info page, but on the correct scenario URL displayed should be www.mydomain.com/info.

I've tried the [r] modifier, but then the page redirects to www.mydomain.com/C:\htdocs\info.php

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've got relative links in your search page. The URL `/search/keyword` is 2 "virtual folders" deep and the browser (knowing nothing about the actual `search.php` page) believes that relative links should have the base `/search`.

Try making your links absolute URLs or add this to your page header:

```
<base href="/" />
```

---

EDIT:

> Adding the following lines to htaccess gives me a partial solution:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} search/(.*)
RewriteRule ^search/(.*) $1 [qsa]
```

> The "info" link on the search points to the url www.mydomain.com/search/info, that redirects successfully to the info page, but on the correct scenario URL displayed should be www.mydomain.com/info.
>
> I've tried the [r] modifier, but then the page redirects to www.mydomain.com/C:\htdocs\info.

You need to add a slash before the `$1` to tell apache that you're referring to a URL-path and not a file-path.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} search/(.*)
RewriteRule ^search/(.*) /$1 [L,R,QSA]
```

The rule needs to be before your other rules.

Comment: That is obvious. I'm asking if the same can be achieved with .htaccess, and leave the hyperlinks untouched.

Comment: @fcaserio if you know what keywords you want to do this for (which means you'll never be able to search for "about" anymore), then you just need to add redirects for each one of your broken links: `RewriteRule ^search/about$ /about [L,R=301]`

Comment: I posted a simplified version of my scenario. That could be done in the way you pointed, but I have a large number of possible URLs on the project. The ideal would be redirect based on HTTP_REFERER

Comment: Adding the [R] modifier causes the Apache to redirect to: www.mydomain.com/C:\htdocs\info, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @fcaserio you need the leading slash in your target, e.g. **`/$1`**